# When are SQLiteOpenHelper methods called?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm struggling to understand the idea behind `SQLiteOpenHelper`. It has `onCreate()`/`onUpdate()` methods which should be overridden, but I don't understand what calls them or when they are called. Will Android call those methods when the app is run at the first time (which doesn't happen in my case), or I should call them manually? I consulted the documentation but couldn't find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overriden methods like 'onCreate' are called by the framework when you request a readable and or writable databse (in case it's not created). 'onUpgrade' is useful if you develop the app and change the database version, that's the part where it's called. The framework will take the biggest parts. You'll call the methods from your datasource class. 
For a longer explanation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

And a great tutorial: 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 2):

They are called automatically at the time when you create the object of class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and request for read/write.

Technically, `onCreate` method is called when it detects that the database file is not already available. It is called only once unless you clean the application data. But the `onUpdate` is called when ever the **version number** of your database is found to be incremented.